# How to use Global Variables from Imported Functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, module

Say 'Mathematics' is a Module downloadable from Pypi. It contains the following function:

```
def addition(a, b):
    global mul

    mul = a * b        
    sum = a + b

    return sum   # only returns sum, mul is not returned
```

I call this function using import like so -

```
from mathematics import addition
ans1 = addition(3, 5)
print(ans)
```

But when I say -

```
ans2 = mul
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'mul'
```

I was hoping to retrieve the value of 'mul' as it has been assigned to be global. 
How can I retrieve mul from an imported function. Had it not been imported, 'mul' would work.
Since the function is imported, obviously the source code of the function 'addition' is not available.

What should be done?

Comment: Please verify that the code you posted actually generates that error message, because it should produce `NameError: name 'mul' is not defined`. (Typo `print(ans)` -> `print(ans1)` aside)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want you can return the value of mul along with add but actually that doesn't make sense....

but if you want to access the value of mul, do

`from mathematics import addition,mul`

mul must be a global var though.

Comment: This worked. However, I can import mul only after I have run addition, otherwise it throws an error. But worked just the way it should. Thanks.

Comment: This does not work. Because only the current value of `mul` is imported into the own namespace. Another reason, why you should not use global variables.

Comment: @Daniel can you elaborate a bit more.....I think you seem to head to a point where I am confused a bit.....you may help me clear my thoughts....what do you mean by current value.... I had tried changing the value in imported addition function but it gave me the initial value of mul where its imported.....what i think is actually its more of a constant being imported......

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global, return both values:

```
def addition(a, b):
    mul = a * b
    sum = a + b
    return sum, mul
```

and assign both to two variables:

```
ans1, ans2 = addition(3, 5)
```

Comment: I dont want it to return multiple values for a reason. I had thought abt that earlier.

Comment: For what reason? Anything is better than global variables.

Comment: In my function, the function returns a dataframe of all metrics. It also returns predicted values, but that is returned as a large numpy array in the jupyter notebook  below the dataframe returned. I just wanted to avoid that. But, yes you're right, anything is better than global variables. I asked this questions to see my options that's all.